# Step Up Converter (Boost) is Wasting too much Power

Tags: power, boost, converter, efficiency

I'm using a boost converter to run a brushless fan (10V, 5Watt, 0.5 Amperes) from a power bank with a 5 Volt output. The converter's efficiency is rated at approximately 85% (from 5 to 10 V). Theoretically the input side of the converter should have a 1 Amp current absorbtion. Instead I'm measuring 2.7 Amps (the power bank can't substain this). In other words to feed a 5 W motor I'm giving 13.5 W.

Are there some reasons for this? Maybe the brushless motor requires some Capacitance?

Comment: What Boost converter?

Comment: Boost efficiency depends on the output current. If you are using it at, say, 10% of max output, I would expect the efficiency to be much lower than the peak efficiency. Provide a link to the boost datasheet.

Comment: What is the voltage at the input? How do you measure the current? Are you using a true RMS meter?

Comment: I'm using a normal cheap meter but, maybe wrongly, I trust on it. By the way I'm using DC, so no worry about RMS (?). In the comment below I inserted the link to the converter so please give a look. As input, for now, I'm using a stable 5V power supply (a 200 W PC one)

Comment: What makes you think the fan is drawing 0.5A? Any motor draws much more current while starting until it's up to full speed. And if the power source can't supply it, it will struggle at low speed and never reach full speed, continually draining its (very high) startup current. So your first step is to measure the actual fan voltage and current. Add that info to the question and we can start to see what's really going on.

Comment: Infact I measured the current and is 0.5 A

Comment: Show us the circuit diagram if it's something you made yourself.

Comment: Edit your question to state that you have in fact measured the fan to draw 0.5 A and not taken the nameplate rating. Also, use your finger. What's heating up?

Comment: Tonight instead of the motor I'll put a resistance of 20 Ohm (V=10V P=5W so R=V^2/P=20 Ohm) and I'll see what is happening. If the power of the input side (of the boost) remain so high is the efficiency of the Boost.

Comment: Where is the schematic, circuit, datasheet?

Comment: I tried with the 20 Ohm resistor and I obtainded this (measured): 
 INPUT(5V@1Amp) OUTPUT(9.6V@0.45Amp) so 4.5W/5W =85% Efficiency as datasheet of the Boost claimed. So is the brushless motor that is problematic. These days I'll try to insert a Cap in parallel. Can be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the figure for the converter efficiency is 85% that means when it is asked to deliver a 5W output (10V @ 0.5A) that the input power requirement is:

> Input Power = Output Power / 0.85 = 5W / 0.85 = 5.88W

At a 5V output of the power bank that would equate to 5.88W / 5V = 1.18A

In the past I did some testing of power banks and USB charging cables and found that there was a considerable voltage drop at the output of the cable due to the both the voltage drop in the cable and the power bank output not staying at 5V when under load.

If we take your measured value of input current as a good reading (2.7A) it implies that the voltage feeding the boost converter is:

> Voltage = Input Power / 2.7A = 5.88W / 2.7A = 2.17V

I encourage you to take a measurement of the actual voltage at the input of the boost converter. It is highly likely that it is not the 5V that you think it is.

It is also possible that the stated efficiency of the converter is not 85%. It could be way lower if the load on the converter was lower than its full rated capacity or if it is a cheap piece of junk with pretend specifications.

Comment: For the test I used as boost input a good power supply (5V stable and measured). I wrote power bank because I would like to use it if the amps were not so high.

Comment: See then what happens when you give invalid information!! If the "good power supply" is truly a valid condition then the last paragraph has to apply or your load is different from what you specify.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so in your opinion is a "bad" converter, is not a "bad" load (brushless motor) that require some sort of stabilization or something other? the converter is this:https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B00HLZNS0Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: I stated that my last paragraph applies OR the load is not as you have described. I have no way of forming a valid conclusion beyond that with the data provided.